# Upload dashboard power bi service with huge size

Tags: powerbi

I’m new here with using Power BI. I have a Power BI report, with a size bigger that 1 GB. Can I upload it on Power BI Service?

Is there any idea or solution that may help or reduce the size of the file? I have a Power BI PRO license.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Power BI report, with a size bigger that 1 GB. Can I upload it on Power BI Service?

Power BI Premium supports [datasets with size over 10 GB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/business-intelligence/datasets-larger-than-10-gb-power-bi-premium). But this costs a lot, and I have doubt this is the solution that you are looking for.

> Is there any idea or solution that may help or reduce the size of the file?

Remove the data you don't need (both rows and more important - columns). Put your data in a normal database (like SQL Server for example) and use [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery) mode instead of import. See [Dataset modes in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand). Storing the data in a proper database, also allows you to aggregate the data before importing it.

Comment: I'm using Snowflake as a source of data, While filing the necessary informations , there is no field that made me choose between Direct mode and import

Comment: Snowflake connector [supports DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/snowflake#capabilities-supported).

Comment: Yes i founded it thank you :) , Just an other question, if the data is already loaded with import method can i switch to the direct query mode ?

Comment: No, tables can be converted from direct query to import, but not vice versa. You'll need to recreate the queries as import queries first. I would highly recommend looking into dataset size reduction first though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/import-modeling-data-reduction https://www.alphabold.com/how-to-reduce-dataset-size-in-microsoft-power-bi/ https://radacad.com/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-power-bi-file-in-a-few-steps